# How to access local IP device from internet

Tags: java, network-programming

I want to make an android based messenger in which I am designing in such a way that both te users who are chatting with each other are servers and client for each other. There is a problem in accessing devices which are in a different network which have one public IP based router and the devices have local IP addresses. I can send message to pubic IP device but I cannot access devices which are inside a local network with a public interface router.
Say 
Sender IP : 130.190.93.68
router IP is : 130.190.09.54
IP of reciever within router private network : 192.168.15.186

Sender wants to communicate with receiver. How can I make it happen using socket programming.

**Edit** Code from comment:

```
public class SocketClient extends Activity {
    private Socket socket;
    private String serverIpAddress = "192.168.15.186";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have a central server that users must sign into, and when a user want to chat with some one else, and if one of the clients are on a private network and the other is not then the client on the private network gets the address of the client on the public network and initiates the chat session.

If *both* clients are on private networks, then it has to go though the server. If none of the clients are on a private network, then the server randomly decides which client should be the client initiating the connection.

Comment: Thanks Joachim but issue is that when I create ServerSocket using code "new ServerSocket(ipAddress,port)" then I need to give IP address and how can I get the IP address of the receiver which is in local network. Can u tell me how does skype contacts get to know each others IP even when the receiver is in a private network.

Comment: @learner Instead of a specific address, there is always a wildcard address, that makes the server socket listen on all interfaces (and therefore all addresses). And Skype, to my knowledge, uses a central directory server much like the one I described in my answer.

Comment: I am pasting the code of my client acessing server. Can u guide me in modifying it for accessing wildcarda ddress

Comment: I have pasted the code can u please guide tomodify it for wildcard adddress accesspublic class SocketClient extends Activity {
   private Socket socket;
   private String serverIpAddress = "192.168.15.186";

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
      tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

         InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
         socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 5000);

Comment: @learner If you create the `ServerSocket` _without_ the address, it will listen for connection from _all_ interfaces.

Comment: Wrote -->One solution is to have a central server that users must sign into, and when a user want to chat with some one else, and if one of the clients are on a private network and the other is not then the client on the private network gets the address of the client on the public network and initiates the chat session.  so client in private network initiated the session users did one request and one response. now when client on public network wants to send another message what address will it use to send its message to client i.e. 130.190.93.68 : 192.168.15.186. I am confused.

Comment: @learner The central server tells the client on the private network "please connect to this address". That connection is _not_ closed, so that both client now can talk directly to each other where the client on the private network acts as the "client" and the other one as the "server". As the connection isn't dropped, when the client on the public network wants to talk to the client on the private network, it just sends a message through the already open connection.

Comment: @learner If you don't want persistent connections, then you have to go through the central server all the time when talking to a client on a private network.

Comment: Thanks Joachim can u plase answer my following question too <br/> [serversocket-error-StrictModePolicy-error-in-logcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328669/android-device-permission-denied-exception-on-new-serversocket6000)