# Android Device : Permission Denied exception on "new ServerSocket(6000)"

Tags: java, android, network-programming

I am getting "Permission Denied" exception on the line `new ServerSocket(6000)` in android device.

I have read a number of posts which says that you must put `android.permission.INTERNET` permission in the manifest. I already have this permission in place and I am still getting this message.

Comment: If you want help, we need more information: post all of your LogCat errors and your Manifest permissions.

Comment: Put your complete code here.

Comment: i got the code from this link [link](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/)

Comment: These are the permissions set in manifest <br/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"> </uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"> </uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"> </uses-permission>

Comment: Same problem with me... I got this issue with port 8...

Comment: @Tariq, port numbers less than 1024 are reserved and can only be opened with root permissions.